# How to map stock ticker symbols to ISIN (International Securities Identification Number)?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, online-data-source, isin

How can I can convert ticker symbols (which include information on the exchange) to an International Securities Identification Number (ISIN) (which contains no information on the exchange)?

Also I am interested in the other way round — given an ISIN and a market identification code (MIC) how can I determine the ticker symbol?

Any databases around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way to convert an ISIN into a stock ticker symbol. The only way to even attempt to do so is to map the ISIN to a CUSIP or SEDOL or other national identifier and then map that identifier to a stock ticker symbol.

Answer (score 18):

It is possible to make a REST API call to [OpenFIGI](https://www.openfigi.com/api) providing the ISIN to get the ticker in the response.

Python code for getting ticker for ISIN=US4592001014:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'
headers = {'Content-Type':'text/json', 'X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY':'myKey' }
payload = '[{"idType":"ID_ISIN","idValue":"US4592001014"}]'

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore... I get error code 401

Answer (score 1):

> How can I can convert ticker symbols ... to an International Securities Identification Number (ISIN) ... ?

As @Indian Rediff said in [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/2945/98919), it is not possible in general to convert or map stock ticker symbols to ISIN's or vice versa using a number of rules or a mathematical function.

However, you can find out the ISIN for a stock by searching for its ticker symbol or name on [this web page](https://stockmarketmba.com/symbollookup.php) on Stock Market MBA. After you make such a search, locate the row that appears to show the characteristics of the security you are looking for and click on the "Analyze" option under the "Actions" column. This will open up a new page including an "Intro" tab whose contents would include the ISIN of the security along with its many other characteristics.

> ... given an ISIN and a market identification code (MIC) how can I determine the ticker symbol?

You can find out the ticker symbols and exchanges associated with a stock by looking up the security's ISIN on [this web page](https://stockmarketmba.com/lookupisinonopenfigi.php) on Stock Market MBA again.

These features on the mentioned web site are not only free (at least for now) but also has extensive international coverage based on the data from [OpenFIGI](https://www.openfigi.com) which is also mentioned in [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/85264/98919) by @John Wood.

---

Update (12 October 2022)

While one still can look up an ISIN on Stock Market MBA, it appears it is no longer possible to look up the ticker symbol of a stock and get the ISIN on the same site, only the SEDOL.