# How to get ISIN by Ticker?

Tags: isin

I need to get a list of ISINs for all my equities tickers. All online services I checked do the opposite (convert ISIN to ticker). I need ticker to ISIN. Any solution for that?

For example, I want to get ISINs for all Nasdaq tickers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map stock ticker symbols to ISIN (International Securities Identification Number)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/how-to-map-stock-ticker-symbols-to-isin-international-securities-identification)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer. It's again about ISIN->Ticker conversion. I need vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

[stockmarketmba.com](https://stockmarketmba.com/symbollookup.php) is the closest I found so far, but you would need to scrape the ISIN from the web page. The [Quantel Api](https://rapidapi.com/Quantel/api/quantel-io/) also returns ISINs (e.g. the GET /profile/{tickers} method) but does not support all the exchanges I require. Websites isin.org supports some database lookup but no ticker lookup. isin.net, isin.com are complete fake. I wonder why it is so hard to get a reliable source for this data, after all it is not very dynamic data. I am currently stuck with ISINs on my system since I use them as primary key, but I wish there was a more accessible alternative.

Comment: >The Quantel Api also returns ISINs (e.g. the GET /profile/{tickers}
I tried msft and aapl. it's empty result for isin and other fields. Not sure how it can be used.

Comment: Quantel works fine

Comment: Did you use other queries / parameters?

Comment: No, I need only ISIN and 'profile' worked fine for me.

Comment: unfortunately, Quantel does not support preferred shares and some other assets types.